# Integração entre dois bancos de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, firebird

Estou com uma ideia de integrar dois bancos de dados, em um ponto tenho o banco *PostGresSql* com o sistema A e no outro lado um banco *Firebird* no sistema B.

> Por exemplo: Gravei um cliente no sistema A e preciso exportar para o
>   sistema B.

Além de criar uma *trigger* e jogar para um banco intermediário e depois fazer uma aplicação para se comunicar e inserir no sistema B.

**Qual seria a outra maneira de fazer isso? ou a melhor forma?**

Comment: Pesquise por Firebird Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @anonimo eu pesquisei mas não consegui entender direito.Consegue dar uma explicação bem breve do que seria esse Data Wrapper?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: Aqui está outro cara que pode te ajudar
https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Getting_Started/GettingStarted_Title.html#concept_htw_ghg_jq